# User secure text keyboard without secure text enable in text field?

Tags: ios

I want to use below image keyboard with **".?123"**.
When we enable secure text for a password in UITextField it displays below the keyboard.

I want to display this keyboard without secure text in other UITextField.

Let me know if anybody has a solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set keyboard type from attribute inspector from story board..

[image]

You can also set it programatically like this

```
txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
```

So you can check it like this...

```
if txtField.isSecureTextEntry {
        txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default // whatever you want to set.
    }
```

Comment: This solution is not working. I want to display keyboard showing in above image. If I set type default then also it is not showing this keyobard.

Answer (score 0):

By default iOS Doesn't change the keyboard either the entry is secure or not.

Keyboard style is an independent property from data entry security.

You can change the keyboard type to `.default`, `.numberPad`, `.phonePad`, `.email`, `.url` by setting it to the property `keyboardType` of `UITextField` object.

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
```

You can also achieve above task from your `Storyboard` or `Xib` to know how to use in `Xib` and `Storyboard` please refer to [Mahendra GP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5020932/mahendra-gp)'s answer above.

Comment: This solution is not working. I want to display keyboard showing in above image. If I set type default then also it is not showing this keyobard.

Comment: What kind of keyboard its showing in default? Share Screenshot.